# How to make the "number of returns" a variable

Tags: python, function, variables

Lets consider a normal function:

```
def function(stuff):
    return result
```

To call it and get the result in a variable:

```
variable = function(stuff)
```

I can do the same with 3 (for example) results:

```
def function(stuff):
    return result1, result2, result3
```

To call it and get the results in 3 variables:

```
variable1, variable2, variable3 = function(stuff)
```

My question is: How can I write a function that automatically reads and changes when I set a variable called "number of results". Or, in my real case, the "number of results" will depend on the length of my variable stuff (the variable stuff is a list of arrays).

I hope this question was not answered before.

Comment: Any time you need to deal with a varying quantity of data, the answer is to use a variable-size container such as a list.

Comment: @LSerni that *is* returning a tuple.

Comment: @LSerni to elaborate on the above, a tuple can be [specified](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) by just `val1, val2` without parentheses.

Comment: You are only returning one result in both cases, one type `T` then other type `Tuple[T]`. You are using unpacking to extract the values of the tuple nto individual variables but you could have equally done `var = fn()` and then `var == (r1, r2, r3)`. Given, all `Iterable` types are variable length you could use anyone of them. But special handling will need to happen with `1` because an `Iterable[T]` is different that `T` itself.

Comment: @AChampion: that is a great point. The syntax is a bit weird, but as an alternative to handling it specially in the function, you can unpack a single value using `(a,) = fn(1)`

Answer (score 4):

You can create a `list` with the number of elements you want, then `return tuple(yourList)`.

However, you could then just return the `list` directly. Python idiomatically doesn't care much about the return types of stuff, so any caller that is looking for an iterable like `tuple` can iterate over the `list` just as well.

A `list` can be unpacked, as well:

```
>>> foo(3)
[1, 2, 3]
>>> a, b, c = foo(3)
>>> a
1
>>> b
2
>>> c
3
```

Answer (score 2):

Just construct and return a *container* of results (such as a `tuple` or `list`):

For example:

```
import random

def function(stuff):
    number_of_results = random.randrange(1, 4)
    results = tuple(random.randint(0, 100) for _ in range(number_of_results))
    return results

for _ in range(5):
    print(function(None))
```

Sample output:

```
(0, 28)
(66,)
(62, 63, 88)
(99, 89, 67)
(87, 91)
```

If you want to assign the values `return`ed to separate variables, you can, but knowing how many the function will return will be necessary. For example, if you somehow knew **in advance** it was going to return three things, you could write: `variable1, variable2, variable3 = function(stuff)`. For that reason it would probably be better to just expect it to return a container and process its contents following the call to the function.

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you for your reply.

I do know how many results I need. But how can I write "variable1, variable2, variable3, ..., variableK = function(stuff)" in an way that would depend on the value of "number of results = K" ?

Comment: I believe I found a solution for this

Comment: Then only way I can think of would be to have a series of `if`, `elif` statements for every number of results expected, and then within each one write the appropriate `v1 = function(stuff)` or `v1, v2 = function(stuff)`, `v1, v2, v3 = function(stuff)`, etc. Obviously that is going to be very tedious and ugly looking. That's why I **strongly** suggest that you instead just expect the function to always return a `list` or `tuple` of values and do any follow-on processing based on the length of that (or the expected length since that is already known).

Comment: a = function()

for i in range(len(a)):
    globals()["variable%s" % i] = a[i]

Is this the best way to do it?

Thank you again for your help

Comment: Yes, that looks like it would work, although using globals is generally a bad idea (see [this article](http://wiki.c2.com/?GlobalVariablesAreBad) for why).

Comment: Although that works, as I said, what about the rest of your code? How is it going to know which variable were defined and are valid?

Comment: The function only returns valid variables and its built to calculate how many results is going to return during its operation. What I didnt know is that, inside the function, I could and needed to store the results in a list of tuple before returning them. My problem is solved now, thank you very much for your help